# Elasticsearch for Jira-like System with Permissions

Tags: java, tomcat, elasticsearch, full-text-search, jira

We have a Jira-like Systems with some hundreds of Projects. It runs on a two-node Tomcat cluster on two differen phisical machines but using the same database. A tipical user have permissions to some (maybe to some dozens of) projects, she can see only data from that projects. Both tickets and projects have some dozens of attributes.

I would like to implement a global search for that application, both quick search (i.e. search globally in object attributes) and custom search (i.e. search criteria for some attributes). This functionalities should also handle permissions.

Is ElasticSearch a good basis for that?

As for architecture I would embedd one Node and one Client into each of our Tomcat webapp, and cluster this Nodes. Is it a good idea? (The application management is separated and it is  not so easy to make such a big change as the instalation of new tools like standalone ElasticSrach.)

On the other hand, is there some appropriate setup in ElasticSearch for handling permissions, and having quick search and custom search?

What would be the proposed way of updating the ElasticSearch indexes? I guess I should push data from my app to ElasticSearch, whenever some attributes of a Ticket or a Project changes resp. new comment is added resp. new Ticket or Project is created.

Comment: What do you mean by "Jira-like Systems"?

Comment: Jira like means that we have business processes (~Jira tickets) of some type (~Jira ticket type), each particular process belongs to a B2B contract (~Jira project). Both processes and contracts have several attributes, also comments, these are stored in DB.

Comment: So in fact you are *not* using atlassian jira. However, Jira is using Lucene to index issues and comments (and all the fields), and has an own query language that is (almost) directly transformed to lucene queries. These indexes are used everywhere (searches, filters, dashboards), except when directly viewing the issue. Much faster than doing it in dbms.

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of questions, I'll do my best to answer them:

**Security**: ES has no build in security out of the box for free.  They just released "Shield" which is their security and access control, it requires Gold level support for you to use it.

**Where to put your ES nodes**: ES takes up a **LOT** of resources, especially JVM memory.  I recommend that you think of ES in the same way you'd think of SQL Server/Oracle: in production they should have own machines/VMs.  ES Support recommends that you run at least 3 production nodes.

**Speed**: ES is amazingly good at:

1. Searching large quantities of data
2. Searching data in lots of different fields
3. Aggregating data much, **MUCH** faster than SQL.

Hopefully that is helpful.

Comment: Then I perhaps need something like Hibernate Search? Anyway, it is not a big traffic system, clustering is just for fault-tolerance. Whatever I choose, the clustering and embedded running seems somehow contradicting.